# C# how to define fancy objects (textbox, button, etc...) in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, button, textbox, label

I know how to define an array of int[i], byte[i], and so on.  Love it because I can use the for loop to run them.  Now I am thinking of doing the same thing with fancy objects like textbox, button, label, etc...  I wonder if that is possible.

In case it is, how can that be done?  And how will the name of the object be?  something like mytextbox[1], mylabel[2]?

Comment: it would be an `object[]` or, an array of some other more derived interface shared by all members but, if you love arrays, you must really love `List<T>`, no?

Comment: you can make a List<Control>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly right.

```
TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[10];
```

Or, you can create an array of type `Control` and use it with any sort of control:

```
Control[] myControls = new Control[10];
myControls[0] = new TextBox();
myControls[1] = new DropDownList();
```

In order to add these to your Form, you'll have to add each to the `Controls` property of the form dynamically.

```
foreach(Control control in myControls)
{
    Controls.Add(control);
}
```

You'll have to set the properties of each control in your code behind as well, such as the `Id`, the `Text`, etc, as well as the `Height`, `Width`, `Top` and `Left`. That is how you'll place each control where you want on your form.

Comment: OK, then after defining them as above how do I bring them to my form in the design window? I mean, each of them from TextBox[0] to TextBox[10].

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how to use the array of controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a generic list that can contain all of them but keep in mind that afterwards you will not be able to access their properties if you don't know what type those elements are.

So, if you do something like an array of Labels (or List so you don't define the size):

```
List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>();
```

then it's ok because you can iterate through them with a for/foreach and to whatever you need to do.

If you want to build a non homogenous list of items, to put both Labels, Textboxes and others in, then keep in mind that you will have to put in extra effort to determin what list[i] is before you actually work with that object.